# add dates to a bind variable date field

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oraclereports, ora-00932

We are using oracle 12c forms and reports. In one of the query the users will enter the date through forms and the below mentioned query will fetch the required data.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM T_APPLICATION_HDR,T_APPLN_PENSIONER
 WHERE APPLN_PK=APEN_APPLN_PK
 AND APPLN_DATE <=:APPLN_DATE
 AND APPLN_SECN_ID ='PV1'
 AND APPLN_STAT='04'
```

What i require is from the above query the data fetched will be prior to the date entered by the users. I want to add 10 days to the date entered by users and records populated based on that date.

i modified the above query like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM T_APPLICATION_HDR,T_APPLN_PENSIONER
 WHERE APPLN_PK=APEN_APPLN_PK
 AND APPLN_DATE <=:APPLN_DATE+10
 AND APPLN_SECN_ID ='PV1'
 AND APPLN_STAT='04'
```

It gives this error

> `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER.`

How do i modify this query

i modified the above query like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM T_APPLICATION_HDR,T_APPLN_PENSIONER
 WHERE APPLN_PK=APEN_APPLN_PK
 AND APPLN_DATE <=:APPLN_DATE+10
 AND APPLN_SECN_ID ='PV1'
 AND APPLN_STAT='04'
```

For example if the `appln_date` entered is `10-may-2019`, then the query should fetch records prior to `20-may-2019`.

It gives this error

> `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER.`

How do i modify this query

Comment: The way you modified your query is the correct one. Something else is causing this error. Two things to check (and to share with us after you check): (1) the data type of column `APPLN_DATE` in your table. (Almost certainly `date`, otherwise you would have gotten the same error even before modification, but it's always best to check.) (2) the data type of the variable created by your application and assigned to the bind variable in the query. That seems to, somehow, be seen as `number` by the query parser.

Comment: 01) the data type of column APPLN_DATE is date 02) the data type of the variable assigned to the bind variable is number

Answer (score 1):

'10-may-2019' is not a date, it's text string. In the first case Oracle is smart enough to convert the text string to a date. In the first case Oracle is able to do the conversion but in the second case it gets confused.

I suggest changing your code to be

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM T_APPLICATION_HDR,T_APPLN_PENSIONER
 WHERE APPLN_PK=APEN_APPLN_PK
 AND APPLN_DATE <= TO_DATE(:APPLN_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY') + INTERVAL '10' DAY
 AND APPLN_SECN_ID ='PV1'
 AND APPLN_STAT='04'
```

Comment: I changed the code as you had mentioned and it works the way i want it to.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM T_APPLICATION_HDR,T_APPLN_PENSIONER
 WHERE APPLN_PK=APEN_APPLN_PK
 AND APPLN_DATE <= TO_DATE(:APPLN_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY') + INTERVAL '10' DAY
 AND APPLN_SECN_ID ='PV1'
 AND APPLN_STAT='04'

Comment: @lakshminarayan: I think that what Barbaros was saying was that if the answer solved your problem you should "accept" it by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer text.